# How to Connect pgAdmin on a remot postegresql server with VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, pgadmin-4

Actually ,  I installed (pgAdmin ) to access and manage a psql data-base locateded on a remote sevrer , so I'm connected on a VPN network via my computer (FortiClient ) , I'm blocked cause i can not access to this data base .
I need to know What i have  to configure exactely , because i have 2 ip adresses that i need to connect via my local pgAdmin : the first one is a getway of the VPN connexion , the second is an ip adress of the psql server.
Any help and explanation please

[pgAdmin erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a5fE.png)
[VPN network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaAs6.png)

Comment: Can you able to connect with psql?

Comment: The solution is just allowing the VPN's network in postgresql.config